# Call ajax to servlet call always the error function

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, ajax, servlets

I'm trying to do some tests with ajax and servlet but when I launch the application, the servlet return always 'error'

```
package servlet;

import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;


@WebServlet(name = "ServletCatalogue", urlPatterns = "/test")
public class ServletCatalogue extends HttpServlet {
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.write("test");
    }
}
```

```js
$(function() {
    $("#catalogue").on('click', function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/test",
            type: "GET",
            success: ok,
            error: error
        });
    });
});

function ok() {
    alert("fine")
};

function error() {
    alert('error')
}
```

Why does it always print `"error"`? I know that the JS calls the servlet correctly  because I put a `system.out` to check that.

Comment: It runs the error handler because the request does not return a `2xx` HTTP response code. You need to diagnose why that is.

Comment: open `/test` in your browser and paste the errors from the page

Comment: Try to add the status parameter to error event handler method and see what is the reason for the error, could be that your server is not accessible .

Comment: try to commit the response by `out.flush();`. See if you get the response back to browser level.

Comment: @Sagar if I go to \test it prints 'test'

Comment: add these parameters to your error js function - Function( jqXHR jqXHR, String textStatus, String errorThrown ) and alert textStatus & errorThrown , https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: May be you are not calling function properly. place brackets after calling OK and error like `success : ok()` and `error : error()`

Answer (score 0):

I am using Java Servlet to receive the call. First of all get what is the reason. I did that using the following function

```
function ajaxFailure(data, textStatus, errorThrown){
                alert("OH NO! data: "+data + ' textStatus: ' + textStatus + 'errorThrown: ' + errorThrown);
             }
```

I found the error was due to errorThrown: No conversion from text to application/json
Then I changed the **application/json** to **text** in the $.ajax call.That fixed my issue